# Preserve bounds in allocation in intrinsic assignment

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am using automatic allocation on assignment to calculate the difference of two arrays, with bounds starting at 0:

```
program main
   implicit none
   integer, allocatable :: a(:), b(:), c(:)

   allocate(a(0:10))
   allocate(b(0:10))

   a = 1
   b = 2

   write (*,*) lbound(a)
   write (*,*) lbound(b)

   c = b - a

   write (*,*) lbound(c)
end program main
```

Both, gfortran and ifort give the output:

```
       0
       0
       1
```

Why doesn't c have the same bounds as a and b? Is there a short and concise (without an explicit allocate) way of making sure c has the same bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why doesn't c have the same bounds as a und b?*

Because it shall be allocated to the same shape as `a` and `b` and starting at the lower bound of the expression on the right hand side. The `b-a` is an expression and it starts at 1 and any result f array arithmetic operations will start like that. What if `b` and `a` start at different indexes?)

*Is there a short and concise (without an explicit allocate) way of making sure c has the same bounds?*

No. But you can at least explicitly allocate with `mold=a` or `source=a`.

Comment: The problem also exists for `c = a` aswell, so it's not just do to the operator, but I will use the mold solution.

Comment: There are errors present in some version of compilers for mold= and source=. For example in gfotran 8 to 11 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89925

Answer (score 4):

Consider an intrinsic assignment statement where the left-hand side is not allocated and is an array:

```
variable = expr
```

In such a case, the array `variable` is allocated to the shape of the expression `expr`, with lower bound equal to the value of `LBOUND(expr)` (see Fortran 2018 10.2.1.3).

For the example of the question

```
c = b - a
```

the right-hand side is the expression `b-a`.  For this expression `LBOUND(b-a)` is equal to 1: `b-a` is not a whole array (F2018 16.9.109).  The lower bound of `c` on allocation is thus 1.

The only way the variable assigned to in intrinsic assignment with allocation to have lower bound not 1 is for the right-hand side to have lower bound not 1.  In the assignment (`c` not allocated)

```
c = b
```

then `c` has lower bound that of `b`.

You could avoid an explicit allocate statement with

```
c = b
c = c - a
```

but that is rather unclear and (to repeat a point in Vladimir F's answer) would you want the lower bound to be that of `b` or `a` if these differ.

For completeness:

```
allocate(c(7:17), source=b-a)
```